# Book about man seeking revenge against Odin

Tags: story-identification

Read a book a long time ago that I can't remember the name of.

A soldier with a magic knife seeks revenge against Odin for stealing a friend's soul after a car accident.

Comment: When was "a long time ago"? What language/nationality was it? Was it a short story, novella or full novel? Was it aimed a kids, YA or adults? Anything you remember about the cover? Any character names?

Comment: American Gods??

Comment: -1 I usually support [tag:story-identification] questions, but this, really, doesn't even _try_. Following @Moogle's suggestion would likely revert the downvote.

Comment: They were US soldiers stationed in Germany, Odin killed his friend secretly outside of battle so he could have his soul to fight. I'm looking for it too.

Comment: @JosephBrown: In general, we ask people to write their own question, just in case it does turn out to be different books.

Answer (score 7):

A partial match is [Sleipnir by Linda Evans](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/0671875949/0671875949.htm). The hero, Randy Barnes, is a GI and carries a magic knife called Sly Biter, and he is hunting Odin. A friend of his, Klaus Bjornssen, does get killed but it's a climbing accident not a car accident and Odin doesn't steal his soul.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the Iron Druid Chronicles by Kevin Hearne.  Protagonist is a 2000 year old Druid with a magic sword who ends up fighting gods from almost every pantheon.  Except for Coyote, they are cool.